# Usage of strip_tags()

Tags: php

I am using `strip_tags()` in my php project.

What actually `strip_tags()` does? And can I apply it for `<textarea>` (descriptions), email field?

Comment: Read [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: If you don't know what it does, why are you using it in the first place?

Comment: One of the most important things to learn as a developer is this: Learning how to google, without that particular skill you will have a very hard time.

Comment: Totally agree to @Epodax. One hint for PHP look at [manuals](http://php.net)

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags` in PHP removes the HTML tags from a string.

Consider a PHP variable:

```php
$string = "<p><span>Hello</span> world!</p>";
echo $string; //will output <p><span>Hello</span> world!</p>
echo strip_tags($string); //will output Hello world!
```

If it takes only one argument, that being the string itself it will remove all the tags from that string. But you can also tell what tag to remove:

```
strip_tags($string, "<span>"); //output will be <p>Hello world!</p>
```

For more information read [this](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.strip-tags.php).

Answer (score 0):

Using this function, you can filter all HTML tags from a variable. Furthermore, you can also specify which HTML tags should not be filtered.

```
$text = '<p>This is a sample text.</p><b>Text data.</b>';
```

Eg. 1: Filter all HTML tags.

```
echo strip_tags($text);  // This is a sample text.Text data.
```

Eg. 2: Filter all HTML tags except p tags.

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<p>');  // <p>This is a sample text.</p>Text data.
```

Refer to this for further information: [strip_tags() example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#refsect1-function.strip-tags-examples)